# How do you set up Craft CMS to back up your site automatically?

Tags: config

I am considering having my site moved from WordPress to Craft CMS (feel free, by all means, to weigh in on this consideration), and wondered how one goes about setting up automatic backups within Craft. Thanks!

Comment: Would you accept an answer on how to backup the site server-side? Probably a better solution then from within the site.

Answer (score 11):

Options:

1) Craft will automatically run a backup of the database anytime an update is performed and save it to `craft/storage/backups`

2) You can manually create a database backup by going to Settings->Tools->Create Database Backup.

3) You can install something like the [Dump](https://github.com/putyourlightson/Craft-Dump) plugin and create a cron job that points to it to run the backup on a automated schedule.